# attach file to a message

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I want to attach a file to a message similar to face-book messaging.
on clicking the attach button, the browse window should open.
and on selecting the file, the file must upload and in that page it self it must show the file name.
if the user wants, it should be possible to remove that item.
please anybody help.
Google returns null.

me created a form.

```
<input type="submit" id="upload" value="$" style="margin-left: -10px;" onclick ="javascript:document.getElementById('file').click();" />
<form >
  <input name="file" id="file" size="1" type="file" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px;height: 1px;float: left;" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
</form>
```

Comment: and what have you done so far ?

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not for "can you code this for me" requests. If you are looking for somebody to write something for you, maybe consider oDesk to find freelancers.

Comment: i am really sorry.
me created a form.
now edited the question.
can u please tell me at least what to do to upload the file to the same page and show it as an attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the file upload, to a script on your server in an ajax request.

Maybe you should try a jQuery plugin which fits your needs.

Here is a nice list of uploader plugins: http://www.tutorialchip.com/jquery/9-powerful-jquery-file-upload-plugins/

Comment: me done the eighth method [Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) its working perfectly with drop down area and me edited the code too..
very happy with that..
:D

Answer (score 0):

[PHP - File Upload on tizag.com](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)